# How do you keep a window in all spaces?

Tags: spaces, mission-control

Some apps have this as an internal feature, but is there any way to keep a specific window visible no matter which space you're in?

Answer (score 11):

I figured out how to keep an entire application on any screen.

1. Right click the application in the dock
2. Mouse-ver **Options**
3. Select **All Desktops** from the **Assign to** sub-menu.

But what if I just want, say one spreadsheet in excel to follow me to any desktop, while it keeps the rest where they are?

Comment: However on newer versions of OSX / macOS Mission Control contains a bug that will make the application you select in expose immediately jump back/behind the app you were currently using. This makes the feature useless, at least for me.

Not really a comment on your post, just a note for people running into the bug.